# Android kitkat cross-domain ajax failing

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, webview, cross-domain

I have an Android app that loads an html file into a WebView from the assets folder. Javascript in that file then attempts an Ajax call to retrieve data from a remote server. The attempt succeeds on a 4.1 device but fails on a 4.4 device.

Relevant code in the Activity's onCreate:

```
mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
```

And in the head element of test.html (which contains no other javascript):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/zepto.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready( function()
    {
        var url = 'http://google.com';
        $.ajax(
        {
        type: 'GET', 
        url: url, 
        success: function(dataAsText) 
        {
            $('#report').html("Success");
        },
        error: function( xhr, type)
        {
            $('#report').html("Error");
        });
    });     
</script>
```

-- I Get Success on 4.2, Error on 4.4.

According to the documentation, webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true); is supposed to enable the cross-domain call.

I'm using zepto; I tried using jquery instead and the same happened.

I understand that WebView is significantly changed in KitKat. Is there some other security-related setting I'm missing?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Answered my own question: it seems the default behaviour with regards to adding a WebViewClient has changed: when I add a subclass of WebViewClient that returns false from shouldOverrideUrlLoading for the URL in question, it works on 4.4. On 4.1, it worked without this.